# omniauth Authentication failure! ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: rails 7 API and React Native

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native

While passing my google token to the rails API, I am getting the following error:

> D, [2023-04-12T21:00:33.554171 #89420] DEBUG -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
> E, [2023-04-12T21:00:33.586561 #89420] ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure!
> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken, ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
> Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
> Parameters: {"idToken"

I have the following gems installed:

```
gem 'omniauth', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'omniauth-apple', '~> 1.3'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
gem "omniauth-rails_csrf_protection"
gem 'rack-cors'
```

In my devise.rb file I have the following added>
`OmniAuth.config.allowed_request_methods = %i[post]`

This works with a normal rails 7 app and a request to google though for the mobile app it is triggering the InvalidAuthToken.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your setup for the backend and client side, but it could be that your client side in React Native is attempting to trigger API call from your backend without passing authenticity token so Rails is treating this as CSRF and raises an error. You can try adding
`skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` callback into Rails controller to see if it helps.

Otherwise you can see if you can fix this by adding the Rails authenticity token into the request params, but you will have to fetch it in your client side first and then maybe pass it as hidden field value.

Another option that might work is to restructure your code so that the API call is initiated and processed on the backend completely within the Rails, but again I don't know your app setup so please treat this as a list of possible ways to resolve your issue.